# Weekly DAG running twice

Tags: cron, airflow

We have a DAG with the schedule 0 0 * * 1. This should run every Monday at midnight. It *is* running Monday midnight's, but it is *also* running, unrequested at 6:01am on Monday's.

We have other weekly dag's that run fine, some set to 1 7 * * sat, etc. Has anyone else had issues with the 0 0 * * X schedule? Or is it possible that something in the actual dag code is re-triggering the dag to run again?

Comment: For the unrequested DAG run at 6:01am on Monday, does its run id start with `scheduled_`?

Comment: It does, indeed.

Comment: Yeah that's odd. Airflow uses croniter to get the schedule intervals for a cron string. I plugged in `croniter('0 0 * * 1', datetime.utcnow())` and calling `cron.get_next(datetime)` consecutively didn't get me any unexpected behavior. I assume if your dag code is triggering dag runs you would know about it (and you choose the run id for that). Are you using the stable version 1.8.2? I know timezone support was recently added to master, this issue sounds like it could be related?